# java: how to include long list of compiled class files to jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a long list of compiled classes in java. I want to use them in my project. How to add all those classes in jar file? Or maybe there is possibility to get java sourse files from compiled java class files?

I find I can generate jar using:

```
jar cf jarname input-files
```

And as I understand instaed of `input-files`I need to specafy the whole list of my compiled classes. But it would be very uncomfortable. I have near 50 classes.

Comment: Just include the class files (in an appropriate folder structure) in the jar file when you build it. It's not clear what you've already tried...

Comment: Would this help ?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Consider using Apache Ant as a build automation tool. It makes tasks such as what your describing simple and neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Maven or Ant. It is very easy to start with them and they can give you much more than building a jar file.

Maven - simple pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

You just need to run "mvn install" command and your jar file will be created in target folder.

Ant - look at http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Or just google for Maven or Ant.

Answer (score 0):

The java world often requires astonishingly long command lines.  Don't worry about it.

If the class files are by themselves in a directory structure, you can just include the root directory - all of the files in it will be put in the jar.

On the other hand, most folks use some higher-level tooling for jarring - Ant, Gradle, or Maven for automated builds; Eclipse or Intellij support if just working from an IDE.

A mistake I made when I was a newbie was not to have the correct root of the jar.  The root directory of the jar must also be the root directory of your package structure.  So, for instance, if your classes are all in `com.foo.mypackage`, there better be a top-level directory in the jar called `com`.